# Do users get notified when incrementing only versionCode?

Tags: android

Do the users of the app get notified about update when I upload a new version of the app with incremented versionCode (manifest), but same versionName?

Edit: And if the versionCode is enough, will the users have to update the app, or is it optional?

Comment: +1, Have you considered opening a bounty on the question?

Comment: A more reliable solution would be to just test it :) but haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The version name is a descriptive string while the version code is an incremental value. I don't think you have to change the version name (even if you should, to inform users they have a new version), but you'll have to change the version code for sure.

Comment: its just for a very small bugfix, that's why I don't want to change the version name. but I want to be sure that the users receive an invitation to make the update.

Comment: Then if it's small, set version name to 1.0.0.1 or something like this.

Answer (score -2):

If you are uploading the apk to the google play  and you are keeping the proper version naming the google play will provide the notification for the upgrade on the apk file